# Separate String with Key value Pair

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I've a string array which has got key and value which are separated using a delimiter. I need to separate the key value pair and move it to a HashMap.

The string is as follows.

```
String[] str={"12345$abcd","12332$abcgd","5555$afdsd"};
/*
 I need to move it to HashMap as key-value pairs
 12345=abcd
 12332=abcgd
 5555=afdsd
*/
```

Can someone please help me to do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency. Try it the way that seems most logical to you. Then worry about optimiation is the solution is too slow. Maybe start with the String API and use indexOf() and substring() methods. Also define "efficient". Any solution that uses a regex will not be the most efficient.

Comment: You should be able to split over 10,000 properties in under 1 milli-second using the most obvious approach.  If this isn't fast enough, then you can optimise it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] str={"12345$abcd","12332$abcgd","5555$afdsd"};

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(final String s : str) {
   final String split[] = s.split("\\$");
   map.put(split[0], split[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] str={"12345$abcd","12332$abcgd","5555$afdsd"};
Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(String string: str){
mp.put(string.split("\\$")[0],string.split("\\$")[1]);
}
```

- [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/xYWum)

Comment: $ is a special regex char. And you'd better not split twice ;)